# Add notification under input text on focus

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, input, push-notification

How to add a notification under an input when focused ?

Like this:

[image: Input Notification]
<sub>(source: [cjoint.com](http://www.cjoint.com/doc/16_11/FKjmWbWGygY_input-notification.jpg))</sub>

Is there any bootstrap plugins for this ?

Thanks,
Vincent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bootstrap plugin for it. have a look at it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Notification in text nox</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">  
 </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">    
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <input type ="text" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">
</div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
       });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Have a good day!!